# Monotouch launch calendar application

Tags: xamarin.ios, icalendar

this question seems simple but I can't find anything on the web. In my application I have a button and just want to call de standard Calendar application from my button. I don't want to add events or stuff like that. I just can't find an OpenUrl or there is another way to call the Calendar app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no URL scheme define for Calendar. You can however allow users to use the standard EventKitUI to create, edit, and display events.

There is also UICalendar to display events:

https://github.com/Clancey/UICalendar

[image]